# Easy and simple SQLite database GUI?

Tags: gui, sqlite

I'm looking for a really simple GUI that interfaces with an SQLite database to facilitate editing/searching a single table, which includes:

- Editing the table in tabular format, like a spreadsheet (not requiring the extra clicks to edit individual fields)
- "live search" filtering of the table

I currently use the [SQLite Manager
Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager-webext/) but it doesn't provide either feature.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835069/which-sqlite-administration-console-do-you-recommend) on StackOverflow.

- [SQLite Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835069/which-sqlite-administration-console-do-you-recommend) is easy to use:

  [image]
- [SQLite Manager](http://www.sqlitemanager.org/) is a little less user-friendly, but offers a web interface:

  [image]
- [phpSQLiteAdmin](http://phpsqliteadmin.sourceforge.net/) is another web-interface that is relatively easy to use:

  [image]

Answer (score 3):

[SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

SQLite Database Browser is a freeware, public domain, open source visual tool used to create, design and edit database files compatible with SQLite. It is meant to be used for users and developers that want to create databases, edit and search data using a familiar spreadsheet-like interface, without the need to learn complicated SQL commands. Controls and wizards are available for users to:

- Create and compact database files
- Create, define, modify and delete tables
- Create, define and delete indexes
- Browse, edit, add and delete records
- Search records
- Import and export records as text
- Import and export tables from/to CSV files
- Import and export databases from/to SQL dump files
- Issue SQL queries and inspect the results
- Examine a log of all SQL commands issued by the application

Download: [V1.3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/files/sqlitebrowser/1.3/) - or - [v2.0 beta1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/files/sqlitebrowser/2.0%20beta1/)

Comment: That looks familiar (I recall testing an SQLite program that had the primitive looking toolbar that SQLDB has). If it’s the same one, then I recall it being troublesome and crashing.

Comment: sorry on delay .. i use this one exclusively and never experienced crashes. although i cannot contest to using it on windows, so...

Answer (score 1):

I love [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) and [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) -- both are great tools, and are compatible with sqlite.

Check out [this page](http://www.dbvis.com/features/tour/table-data-viewer-editor/) for info about DbVis's graphical table editing features.

Answer (score 1):

There are online tools to query SQLite databases:

- ExtendsClass: https://extendsclass.com/sqlite-browser.html
  This website allows to open SQLite file directly in the browser, without installation.
  You can open SQLite file, and view the contents of tables (just click on the name of the table).
- SQLiteOnline: https://sqliteonline.com/
  It is like the previous website, it is easy to use.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[**sqlite-gui**](https://github.com/little-brother/sqlite-gui) is the most simplest GUI for Windows. I'm the author.

Features

- Syntax highlighting and code completion
- Edit multiple tables at the same time
- Colorized data grid
- Store an execution history and user scripts
- Export/Import data
- Database diagram
- Database comparison
- Search text in the whole database
- [Quick data references](https://github.com/little-brother/sqlite-gui/wiki#quick-references)
- [Terminal mode](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/little-brother/sqlite-gui/master/resources/terminal.webp)
- [Charts](https://github.com/little-brother/sqlite-gui/wiki#charts)
- [Query parameters](https://github.com/little-brother/sqlite-gui/wiki#query-parameters)
- Data generator
- [SQLite extension pack](https://github.com/little-brother/sqlite-gui/wiki#extensions)

... and more

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TablePlus](https://tableplus.io/), it's a native app with sleek UI that works well with SQLite.

Also, check out the [simple guide to using TablePlus](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/04/getting-started-with-tableplus.html)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for your contribution, but could you read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) (especially the bit in **bold**) and [update your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1314692/edit) so that it meets requirements. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite Studio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt) - cross platform free software (GPL license).

[image]

[image]